# Lebesgue measurability of singular set

Tags: ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, lebesgue-measure, semicontinuity

Let $\Omega$ be a bounded domain in $\mathbb{R}^{d}$ and $f:Q\to\mathbb{R}$ be continuous function.
Define a *superdifferential* of $f$ at $x\in Q$ by
$$
D^{+}f(x)=\{p\in\mathbb{R}^{d} \mid \text{$f(y)\le f(x)+p\cdot(y-x)+o(|x-y|)$ as $Q\ni y\to x$}\}.
$$

> Is a set
>   $$
> \Sigma(f)=\{x\in Q \mid D^{+}f(x)=\emptyset\}
> $$ 
>   Lebesgue measurable?

I'm facing the above problem, but am not familiar with Lebesgue measure theory and so I don't know how to verify.
Of course, I know that if $f\in C^{1}(Q)$, then $\Sigma(f)=\emptyset$ thus Lebesgue measurable set, and it is clear even if $f\in Lip(Q)$.
However, I'm wondering if this is really true for general continuous functions.

This problem may be fundamental, but I'm glad if you teach me how to discuss.
In addition, I want to consider the same problem for upper semicontinuous functions and so it is great pleasure if you give some comments.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: As a general principle, anything that can be written down easily is measurable.

Comment: I guess $\Omega = Q$.

Answer (score 1):

Seems so. Let's describe the existence of superdifferential as a measurable condition. We denote by $\mathbb{Q}_+$ the set of positive rational numbers, $Z:=(\mathbb{Q}\cap [-1,1])^d$. The existence of supperdifferential at a point $x$ is equivalent to the following condition
$$
\exists R\in \mathbb{Q}_+\, \forall \delta\in \mathbb{Q}_+\, \exists \varepsilon\in \mathbb{Q}_+\,\exists p\in R\cdot Z\,\forall y\in \varepsilon\cdot Z\\
f(x+y)\leqslant f(x)+p\cdot y+\delta\|y\|.
$$
It is clear that if superdifferential exists, this condition holds. To prove the opposite, taking such $p$ for $\delta=1,1/2,1/3,\dots$ and choosing a converging subsequence of $p$'s gives you a genuine superdifferential.